# How do I make the navigation buttons the same level as the logo picture in the header?

Tags: html, css

I am new to html and css. I am trying to create a header. I need to put the logo picture on the left of the header, and have the navigation buttons on the right but on the exact same level right next to it, not below it.

**Further, I want to know how to remove the margins around my nav buttons. Even though I made margin 0 there are still spaces around them.**
How can I do that?
Here is the code I wrote so far:

```css
#logo {
  margin: 25px 18% 0 50px;
}
nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 10px;
  padding: 0;
}
nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Larry Rosenburg Official Website</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div id="logo">
      <img src="lincoln.jpg" width="30%" alt="Lincoln logo">
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li> <a href="index.html"> Home </a> 
          </li>
          <li> <a href="lincoln.html"> Lincoln </a> 
          </li>
          <li> <a href="about.html"> About </a> 
          </li>
          <li> <a href="contact.html"> Contact </a> 
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>

<footer>
</footer>

</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [logo on left and menu on right in same row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7622622/logo-on-left-and-menu-on-right-in-same-row)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing you'll want to do is have both the image and the `nav` containing the links floating next to each other:

```
#logo img, #logo nav {
  float: left;
}
```

Then you'll need to set a line-height on the `nav` element. This height may need to change depending on exactly how big your image is:

```
#logo nav {
  line-height: 100px;
}
```

I've created a fiddle demonstrating this, which can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Obsidian_Age/c4x6p2zn/).

Hope this helps!

**EDIT**

To offset the navbar from the logo, all you need to do is add `margin-right` to `#logo img`, or `margin-left` to `#logo nav`, as they're boat floating next to each other. Here I've used `#logo nav`, as it already had an existing CSS selector:

```
#logo nav {
  line-height: 100px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

Also, keep in mind that you have called your *container* div `logo` -- this actually comprises both the image and the navbar. It's just naming, so it won't affect the way the code works, but might lead to some confusion when you're trying to manipulate `#logo` ;)

There's a new fiddle showing casing the new offset [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Obsidian_Age/yL34br16/) :)

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much! It worked for the most part. But I want the menu bars to float further to the right. Right now it is kind of in the middle of the screen.Should I add margin to #logo nav?

Comment: @Catherine -- I've updated my answer to showcase the navbar floating further to the right. Keep in mind that you can change the value of `margin-left` if you want to increase or decrease how far away it is :)

Comment: I tried margin-left, but there is still a big chunk of white space next to the 'Contact' button. How do I make the menu buttons shift more to the right?

Comment: It depends on your desired output. Assuming you just want to shift the navbar further to the right, simply increase `margin-left` (like try with 100px). Assuming you want to bring both the image and navbar closer to the center of the page, you can decrease the second (right) and fourth (left) parameter in `margin` for `#logo`.

Answer (score 1):

css

```
#logo {
    margin: 25px 18% 0 50px;
}
nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 10px;
    padding: 0;
    display:table;
    border:solid 1px #ddd;
}
nav li {
    display: table-cell;
}
nav li:not(:first-child) {
    padding:0 15px;
    background:#eee;
    position:relative;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

html

```
<header>
<div id="logo">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><img src="lincoln.jpg" alt="Lincoln logo"></li>   
      <li> <a href="index.html"> Home </a> 
      </li>
      <li> <a href="lincoln.html"> Lincoln </a> 
      </li>
      <li> <a href="about.html"> About </a> 
      </li>
      <li> <a href="contact.html"> Contact </a> 
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
</header>
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/u9p3v8r3/)

Answer (score 1):

You could simplify it. Also try not to use inline styles unless mandatory.

```css
#logo {
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
}

nav ul{
  list-style: none;
  width: 70%;
}

nav li{
  display: inline;
}

#header { 
  width: 100%; 
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div id="logo">
    <img src="lincoln.jpg" alt="Lincoln logo">
  </div>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li> <a href="index.html"> Home </a> </li>
        <li> <a href="lincoln.html"> Lincoln </a> </li>
        <li> <a href="about.html"> About </a> </li>
        <li> <a href="contact.html"> Contact </a> </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `float:left` the `#logo img` and put some margin to separate it from the links

Something like this

```css
#logo {
  margin: 25px 18% 0 50px;
}
#logo img {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px
}
nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 10px;
  padding: 0;
  float: right;
}
nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Larry Rosenburg Official Website</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div id="logo">
      <img src="lincoln.jpg" width="30%" alt="Lincoln logo">
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li> <a href="index.html"> Home </a> 
          </li>
          <li> <a href="lincoln.html"> Lincoln </a> 
          </li>
          <li> <a href="about.html"> About </a> 
          </li>
          <li> <a href="contact.html"> Contact </a> 
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>

<footer>
</footer>

</html>
```

Comment: thanks! just one question, when you run the code snippet, you see the white space next to the menu buttons aka right next to Contact. How do I make the the buttons shift left?

Comment: @Catherine Just `float:right` your `nav ul`, I'll update the answer